# Compare two registry files (.reg) and apply the difference

Tags: powershell, registry

I have two registry files (.reg) exported using powershell. I would like to compare the difference of the two files to the registry, ideally using powershell.  I have been using compare-object but that compares the files at the text level. I want to "pre-load" the files into memory and compare them at the key/property level to determine which keys have changed. I would then want to  create a third .reg file with the changes and apply this to the registry.

Is this possible, eg using the Compare-Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple ideas, none of them what I would call good. I cannot find a better way, even using .NET APIs.

1. (Compare-Object): Use 'reg.exe' to export the target tree to a file, then Get-Content both files, and do a Compare-Object on their contents.
2. (Manual): Use get-content on new.reg, then parse each line with either split or regex-fu. For each item, get-itemproperty on the target and validate the values of the properties and child keys
3. (Compare-Object): Import new.reg into temporary registry location, then use Get-ChildItem on both trees and compare all the objects

Comment: I used the second option in the end, but only on each key that needed comparing. So I just compared the whole text file, not line by line. If the file had changed, I know the key has changed.